# when condition is a negative number, how python while will be end

Tags: python, while-loop

Why this code is not infinite loop. I thought if a number in while condition, then it is always True.negative is still a number even though it changes from negative to positive. But when I run this code in spyder, it was stopped after negative is changed to 0.  Why "while" loop stopped when negative changed ?

```
>>> positive = -9
>>> negative = -12
>>> while negative:
...    if positive:
...        print(negative)
...    positive += 3
...    negative += 3
```

Comment: `0` is "falsy" in Python. Try writing a `while 0:` loop and see how many times it executes. Different languages handle this differently, for example `0` is "truthy" in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is zero, it's considered a falsey value and that would cause the loop to end.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/47453 for lots of falsey values.